# How can I generate gettext translations for ecto model field names?

Tags: elixir, gettext, ecto

I have a usual `Ecto.Model` and I need to register its fields as translations to move them to `.pot` file. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

I'm using these field names to prepare list of translated errors:

```
errors = changeset
  |> Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors(fn {msg, opts} ->
    Enum.reduce(opts, msg, fn {key, value}, _ ->
      String.replace(msg, "%{#{key}}", to_string(value))
    end)
  end)

formatted = for {field, messages} <- errors,
                message <- messages,
                do: "#{field} #{translate_error(message)}" # functionality is here

  defp translate_error(msgid) do
    Gettext.dgettext(MyApp.Gettext, "errors", msgid)
  end
```

I want to translate not only message, but field too!

Comment: Are you printing the field names somewhere in any template? What code are you using for that?

Comment: @Dogbert I updated the answer

Comment: asiniy and @Dogbert was this ever answered? What was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with [GettextSchemaField package](https://hex.pm/packages/gettext_schema_field).